# scrolling tabs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, tabs

Is there simple solution to build tabs with the scrolling tabs-pane in jQuery?

Like ExtJS Advanced Tabs:

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.html

Comment: Here is a plugin that does what you expect, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259166/2952405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution - [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html). That's exactly what did i needed.
[This is how did i implemented in tabs](http://orbitscripts.com/products/search/landing/index/?query=John+Smith&tab=17#).

Comment: Updated. You need add tabs with [+] on tab pane to see requested result.

Answer (score 1):

@RayZ, the plug-in has been moved to a it's own place

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html