# How to make Jquery UI Tabs scroll horizontally if there are too many tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, tabs

[image: It appears as multiple line by default.]

Now the image above is an example of " too many tabs ", It appears as multiple line by default.

But I want to make it in a single line and horizontally scrollable, either adding two arrows before the beginning tab and after the last tab, or scroll automatically are OK.

Comment: I am entertained by the fact there are five plugin solutions to the problem on this page. :} I wonder how many more there are.

Comment: @VaelVictus added one more variation in below answer which works with the latest version of jQuery UI library https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259166/2952405

Answer (score 7):

I have a different approach to this issue, as I think a scroll for the tabs is counter-intuitive. I created a plugin to do a dropdown when the tabs break to a second line.

https://github.com/jasonday/plusTabs

Comment: I like this approach better. So much so, I forked Jason's code and updated it to allow as many tabs as possible to display before plugging the remaining tabs into the dropdown tab.  Cheers.  https://github.com/recarv/plusTabs

Comment: Hey @Ross , this was my next step for the plugin. Do you have a demo? and do you want to commit the change? I'd like to make it configurable - true/false.

Answer (score 6):

I was recently looking for a solution to this but none of the other plugins / examples seemed to work with jQuery 1.9+, I also think that Jason's answer of creating a 'more' tab and displaying any extra tabs as a drop down provides the best UI experience, and so I expanded on his answer and created a jQuery plugin for **1.9+** that extends jQuery UI tabs, if the total width of all of the tabs exceeds the width of the tabs container then the additional tabs are grouped together in a dropdown.

[image]

You can see the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/boreded/2JK7K/10/embedded/result/) to see it in action. Try resizing your browser window to see it working.

Or you can view the full plugin code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boreded/2JK7K/10/).

Initialising 'Overflow Tabs' is as simple as this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    overflowTabs: true,
    tabPadding: 23, 
    containerPadding: 40,
    dropdownSize: 50
});
```

`tabPadding` is the number of pixels of padding around the text in a tab.

`containerPadding` is the padding of the container.

`dropdownSize` is the pixel size of the dropdown selector button

I have tested this on the latest versions of `Chrome`, `Firefox`, and `IE`. If you spot any issues or can improve this then feel free to fork it and go ahead.

Now also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/paul-blundell/OverflowTabs).

Comment: Great solution. Do you have plans to put the code to GitHub?

Comment: If you could answer more my questions, I will appreciate. (1) Why one need to configure `tabPadding`? Couldn't it be calculated from `outerWidth` of `<li>` element? Your jFiddle demo states that `padding-left|right` is 0.5em, and the code states `tabPadding: 23(px)` – this is not evident that 1em = 24px. The same concerns `containerPadding`.

Comment: OK, I have found a fixed few other bugs, perhaps they still some left. [Here is my verison](http://jsfiddle.net/c9m99ehc/3/). It has also few bonuses: some tabs are "closeable" and there is "close all" button. The most tricky thing is how to calculate the width of hidden element of the list. The original function `_textWidth` was too tricky as it calculated the width of `<li>` children (?) and thus `tabPadding` parameter was needed for correct functioning. Solution: set `.ui-tabs li {display: inline-block; }` and apply all paddings, margins, borders for `li` and children inside `.ui-tabs`.

Comment: [Another version](http://jsfiddle.net/u3dffhes/2/) this time with [jquery-resize](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-resize/) and [jquery-throttle-debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/) plugins.

Answer (score 5):

None of the plugins listed here quite worked for me (most are outdated and not compatible with jQuery 2.0+) but I eventually found this:
https://github.com/joshreed/jQuery-ScrollTabs
...worth adding to the list.

Answer (score 4):

I've just made a very simple plugin for this. Basically you have to add one fixed length div and a moveable one to the tab navigator.

Plugin code:

```
(function ($) {
var settings = {
    barheight: 38
}    

$.fn.scrollabletab = function (options) {

    var ops = $.extend(settings, options);

    var ul = this.children('ul').first();
    var ulHtmlOld = ul.html();
    var tabBarWidth = $(this).width()-60;
    ul.wrapInner('<div class="fixedContainer" style="height: ' + ops.barheight + 'px; width: ' + tabBarWidth + 'px; overflow: hidden; float: left;"><div class="moveableContainer" style="height: ' + ops.barheight + 'px; width: 5000px; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div></div>');
    ul.append('<div style="width: 20px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
    var leftArrow = ul.children().last();
    leftArrow.button({ icons: { secondary: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w" } });
    leftArrow.children('.ui-icon-carat-1-w').first().css('left', '2px');        

    ul.append('<div style="width: 20px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
    var rightArrow = ul.children().last();
    rightArrow.button({ icons: { secondary: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e" } });
    rightArrow.children('.ui-icon-carat-1-e').first().css('left', '2px');        

    var moveable = ul.find('.moveableContainer').first();
    leftArrow.click(function () {
        var offset = tabBarWidth / 6;
        var currentPosition = moveable.css('left').replace('px', '') / 1;

        if (currentPosition + offset >= 0) {
            moveable.stop().animate({ left: '0' }, 'slow');
        }
        else {
            moveable.stop().animate({ left: currentPosition + offset + 'px' }, 'slow');
        }
    });

    rightArrow.click(function () {
        var offset = tabBarWidth / 6;
        var currentPosition = moveable.css('left').replace('px', '') / 1;
        var tabsRealWidth = 0;
        ul.find('li').each(function (index, element) {
            tabsRealWidth += $(element).width();
            tabsRealWidth += ($(element).css('margin-right').replace('px', '') / 1);
        });

        tabsRealWidth *= -1;

        if (currentPosition - tabBarWidth > tabsRealWidth) {
            moveable.stop().animate({ left: currentPosition - offset + 'px' }, 'slow');
        }
    });


    return this;
}; })(jQuery);
```

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/Bua2d/

Comment: I like what you've done here.  One suggestion I have is that it is not valid html to wrap your li elements inside a div.  Consider wrapping the entire ul element with the divs instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plugin for that: http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/

Comment: Because that JQuery UI Tabs need the tabs and the following contents in the same DIV, and other scroll plugins often need a DIV to contain objects to be scroll. So it's this conflict making me hard to use any plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I've also created an **jQuery** plugin for it [here](https://github.com/LucasLazaro/bootstrap-nav-tab-scrollable), but my main focus was on creating such structure for **mobile sites** that have little space and could rely also on scrolling horizontally with **touch** as well as control arrows.

The solution looks like the following:
[image]

I'm using **Bootstrap** and to implement the plugin you basically need to include:

In you HTML the following structure so the arrows can work correctly  (I'm using font-awesome for them)

```
 <div id="js_image_selection" class="horizontal-scrollable-tabs">
  <div class="scroller arrow-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
  <div class="scroller arrow-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
  <div class="horizontal-tabs">
    <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-horizontal">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#image01" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-white.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image02" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-orange.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image03" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-green.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image01" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-white.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image02" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-orange.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image03" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-green.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image01" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-white.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image02" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-orange.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#image03" data-toggle="tab"><img src="external/images/t-shirt-green.jpg"/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And call in you Js:

```
$("#js_image_selection").horizontalTabs();
```

Hope it helps anyone in the future!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One plugin can be found here https://github.com/Casper1131/scroller
it can be used for any undordered list.

Answer (score 1):

Re: André Lourenço - Great addon, just wanted to throw in a hack that needs refining that allows the scroller to resize on window resize (ie: rotate mobile device);

```
    if(!$(".fixedContainer").length) {
        ul.wrapInner('<div class="fixedContainer" style="height: ' + ops.barheight + 'px; width: ' + tabBarWidth + 'px; overflow: hidden; float: left;"><div class="moveableContainer" style="height: ' + ops.barheight + 'px; width: 5000px; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div></div>');
        ul.append('<div class="leftBtn" style="width: 40px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
        var leftArrow = ul.children().last();
        leftArrow.button({ icons: { secondary: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w" } });
        leftArrow.children('.ui-icon-carat-1-w').first().css('text-align', 'center');        

        ul.append('<div class="rightBtn" style="width: 40px; float: left; height: ' + (ops.barheight - 2) + 'px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0;"></div>');
        var rightArrow = ul.children().last();
        rightArrow.button({ icons: { secondary: "ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e" } });
        rightArrow.children('.ui-icon-carat-1-e').first().css('text-align', 'center');        
    } else {
        var leftArrow = $(".leftBtn");
        var rightArrow = $(".rightBtn");
        $(".fixedContainer").css("width", tabBarWidth);
    }
```

Then I call it again on window resize ie:

```
    $(window).resize(function(e){
        $("#tabs").scrollabletab();
    });
```

Not the most efficient way to do it, but it works for my testing purposes at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I created yet another plugin for this. This time using Chrome style tab-resizing behaviour.

[image: overflowResize]

Initialize with

```
$( ".tabpanel" ).tabs().tabs('overflowResize');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjimenez/1myo7uk3/2/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/adamjimenez/ui.tabs.overflowResize)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios and cases to handle when showing tabs on single line.

1. Simple solution would be to add a `div` around the ui-tab-header `<ul>` and set the overflow as `scroll`. This method works out of box as the browser handles the scrolling through the tab headers. But the default scrollbar provided by browser will look odd. So you need a customize/stylish scrollbar addon. **OR**
2. To use an jQuery UI tabs extension like the below one:

Extended jQuery UI widget that offers scroll-able tab feature and does automatically handle responsive page size changes by showing navigation controls when required.

Features:

- It is responsive or fluid layouts
- Has support for touch swipe to scroll through tab headers in touch devices (* requires external dependency)
- Fully customizable & css based styling
- Supports removal of tabs using close button
- No extra HTML structure changes required, it automatically enhances the markups on the fly.

https://davidsekar.github.io/jQuery-UI-ScrollTabs