# Scrolling Tabs with jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs, scroll

I'm using the following jquery tabs:

```
    $(function() {

    $('ul.tabs').each(function() {
        $(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).click(function(){
                $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
                    .parents('div.section').find('div.box').hide().end().find('div.box:eq('+i+')').fadeIn();
            });
        });
    });
})
```

with the following html:

```
<div class="section">

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="current">Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="box visible">
    <p>Content for box 1.</p>

</div>

<div class="box">
    <p>Content for box 2.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

and so on...

I'm going to have many "tab" items and what I'm trying to accomplish is to incorporate a simple vertical "scroll" on the tab list items as easily as possible.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at this plugin that achieves what you are trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259166/2952405

Answer (score 0):

You can use some css, since you are using

elements to store your content your css file will look like this:

```
p{
height: 200px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

You can use different classes for each

element too

Comment: I'm assuming I need to make some adjustments to my jquery as I don't want to simply have a scroll bar, but want the up and down scrolling through the list to be animated with jquery.