# Jquery tabs with scroll in each tab

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, scrollable

I use jqueryUI tabs and want to implement a smooth scroll bar inside each tab. I tried several scrollable plugins like jQuery custom content scroller, TinyScrollbar and now areaaperta NiceScroll, but each time I stack with the same problem - scrollbar works only inside one tab..

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

    <div id="tabs" style="width:900px; font-size:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" >FIRST</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">SECOND</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">THIRD</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="thisdiv">
        <p><b>FIRST SCROLLABLE PARAGRAPH</b>...</p></div></div>

    <div id="tabs-2"><div id="thisdiv2">
        <p><b>SECOND SCROLLABLE PARAGRAPH</b>...</p>
    </div></div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>THIRD TAB </p>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(
  function() {     
    $("#thisdiv").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
    $("#thisdiv2").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});  }
);
    </script>
```

Here is jsfiddle that shows that there is no  conflicts between UItabs and two scrollbars  of niceScroll plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/Fluc/EhcqX/4/

And here I tried to use same divs with scroll bars inside each tab: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Fluc/cJPT3/2/

As you can see, scrollable works only inside the first tab.. Same with other scrollable plugs..

I'm not jquery programmer but It feels like the problem is related to display property somewhere.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Just have a look at the extended jquery ui tabs mentioned in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259166/2952405