# jQuery UI tabs: add scrolling controls when too many tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there a nicer way/extension of ui tabs which can handle/provide controls for scrolling tabs when there are too many tabs ?

I found some but they dont work with latest jquery-ui-1.10.3.
For example .. [Jizmoz Tabs](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/dECtZ/) is much better in option but does not work with new ui or with jquery 1.9.1.

Any other suggestions ?

**[Jizmoz Tabs JSFIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/dECtZ/)**

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    scrollable: true,
    changeOnScroll: false,
    closable: true
});
```

Comment: May not be what your looking for but you could try twitter-bootstrap tabs http://getbootstrap.com/ it may not have a scroll for tabs but it's pretty responsive.  Tabs that are don't fit will move down below..

Comment: this is by far the best solution for doing this. But like you say only works with specified version :\...anyone can refactor it for the last version of jquery and ui? that would be awesome!

Comment: Check http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-scrollable-tabs demo at http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/#examples

Comment: My answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23802234/1290196 may be of interest to others looking for something similar. This is a plugin that adds a dropdown menu for any tabs that do not fit.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259166/2952405. Works with latest version

Answer (score 2):

This single line works like magic:

```
$(".ui-tabs-nav").hover(function () { $(this).css("height", "auto"); $(this).css("overflow", "hidden"); $(this).css("overflow", "auto"); }, function () { $(this).animate({ height: "32px" }, 600); });
```

It only displays the full tabs when hovering over the tab header, otherwise it only displays the first row of tabs (32px by default but change to suit your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://yourjavascript.com/01913148114/jquery-ui-tabextended.js) library. jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js should be referenced. Example of usage:

```
    $("#tabs").xtabs({
        scrollable: true,
        changeOnScroll: false,
        closable: true
    });
```

this is updated Jizmoz Tabs JSFIDDLE, which is also a changed [jquery scrollable tab](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-scrollable-tabs) of first version. I'm using it with jquery-2.1.1 and everything work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace "_super._create.apply(self);", with "self._superApply(self);"
replace "_super._update.apply(self);", with "self._superApply(self);"
```

It works but with some errors.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit your code? What errors are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for this which uses Chrome style tab-resizing behaviour.

Initialize with

```
$( ".tabpanel" ).tabs().tabs('overflowResize');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjimenez/1myo7uk3/2/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/adamjimenez/ui.tabs.overflowResize)