# Carousel navigation for jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to add a prev/next navigation (as a carousel) to my jQuery tabs but don't know how to accomplish this. Here's what I have so far:

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
            $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
          });
       });
   </script>
```

HTML

```
  <div class="tabs">
    <button id="next-left"> <- </button>
    <button id="next-right"> -> </button>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        content 2
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        content 3
    </div>              
</div>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xUVna/410/)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want all the tabs be on the same line with navigation-arrows for sliding left and right.

I don't think there's a pure jQuery UI solution, but this post might be about the same issue:
[How to make Jquery UI Tabs scroll horizontally if there are too many tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660370/how-to-make-jquery-ui-tabs-scroll-horizontally-if-there-are-too-many-tabs)

Comment: no it should be more a second (alternative) navigation so you can navigate by clicking a specific tab (this is working already) or with the prev/next buttons

Answer (score 0):

okay, I solved the problem, but it's a too much mixing of javascript and jquery now I think (my jquery is not so good...) so maybe someone can show me a (cleaner) jquery-only-code?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xUVna/411/)

html:

```
 <div class="tabs">
    <button class="tab_nav" id="next_left"> <- </button>
    <button class="tab_nav" id="next_right"> -> </button>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" id="link-1" data-tab="tab-1">One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" id="link-2" data-tab="tab-2">Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" id="link-3" data-tab="tab-3">Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        content 2
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        content 3
    </div>              
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab_nav').click(function(){
        if(this.id == 'next_left') {
            $d = 'l';
        }
        if(this.id == 'next_right') {
            $d = 'r';
        }
        $max = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-link').length;
        $currentlink = document.getElementsByClassName('current')[0].id;
        $arraylink = $currentlink.split('-');
        $curlink = $arraylink[1];
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        if ($d == 'l') {
            if ($curlink == 1) {
                $link = "#link-"+ $max;
                $tab = "#tab-"+ $max;
            }
            else {
                $link = "#link-" + ($curlink-1);
                $tab = "#tab-" + ($curlink-1);
            }
        }
        else if ($d == 'r' ) {
            if ($curlink == $max) {
                $link = "#link-1";
                $tab = "#tab-1";
            }
            else {
                $link = "#link-" + (parseInt($curlink)+1);
                $tab = "#tab-" + (parseInt($curlink)+1);
            }
        }
        $($link).addClass('current');
        $($tab).addClass('current');
    });
});
```