# Scrollable Tab Buttons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am preparing a tabpanel where the number of tabs is unknown (comes dynamically). So I am providing a navigation if there are more tabs than the screen size can allow.To achieve this, I use style `margin` since I don't want to use fixed width. But the problem is that I'm unable to move a single tab at a time on click of left/right arrow. Currently I am moving `20px` on a single click which is not accurate.
I am sure there is something I am missing but I'm unable to find it. Can somebody help ?

Any alternative solution is also welcome.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ghdvy6o/).

Comment: Since your tabs have dynamic width based on text content, you’d probably need to query the width of the current “first” resp. “last” tab first, and then adjust the margin by that value.

Comment: Have a look at the following plugin that uses extended jquery UI tabs https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259166/2952405

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here your require tabstrip code. if it useful please up vote.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ghdvy6o/4/)

```
var incWidth = 0, divWidth = 0, OlWidth = 0,marginWidth = 50;
    (function($) {
        $.fn.showScrollIcons = function(){
            OlWidth = $('.checkOL').width();
            divWidth = this.width();
            if(divWidth >= OlWidth){
                $('.arrow').hide();
                if(incWidth){
//                        $('.arrow.leftArrow').show();
                        $('.arrow.leftArrow').hide();
                        $('.showTab').removeClass('showTab');
                        $('.checkOL .checkLI:first-child').addClass('showTab');
                        $('.checkOL').animate({'marginLeft':"+=" + incWidth});
                        incWidth = 0;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $('.arrow').show();
                    if(!incWidth){
                        $('.arrow.leftArrow').hide();
                    }
                    if(divWidth + incWidth >= ( OlWidth - 12 )){
                        $('.arrow.rightArrow').hide();
                    }
                }
            };
        })(jQuery);
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.rightArrow').click(function(){
                var outerWidth = 0;
                var currentTab = $('.showTab');
                if(currentTab.next().length){
                    currentTab.next().addClass('showTab');
                    currentTab.removeClass('showTab');
                    outerWidth = currentTab.outerWidth();
                }
                incWidth += outerWidth;
                $('.checkOL').animate({'marginLeft':"-=" + outerWidth});
                checkArrowHide();
            });
            $('.leftArrow').click(function(){
                var outerWidth = 0;
                var currentTab = $('.showTab');
                if(currentTab.prev().length){
                    currentTab.prev().addClass('showTab');
                    currentTab.removeClass('showTab');
                    outerWidth = $('.showTab').outerWidth();
                }
                incWidth -= outerWidth;
                $('.checkOL').animate({'marginLeft':"+=" + outerWidth});
                checkArrowHide();
            });
            $('.tabBtn').showScrollIcons();
            $( window ).resize(function(){
                $('.tabBtn').showScrollIcons();
            });
            function checkArrowHide(){
                if(!incWidth){
                    $('.arrow.leftArrow').hide();
                }
                else{
                    $('.arrow.leftArrow').show();
                }
                if(divWidth + incWidth >= ( OlWidth - 12)){
                    $('.arrow.rightArrow').hide();
                }
                else{
                    $('.arrow.rightArrow').show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the style. But here is an alternative. using `overflow-x:auto;` you can create a scroll bar automatically when tabs get out of hand.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ghdvy6o/3/)

Comment: Hi Neoaptt, thanks for your reply. Am expecting carousel effect, not this one.