# replicating google material horizontal scrollable tabs in CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, material-design

I'd like to replicate google material's tabs which on mobile or whenever the tabs don't fit in the container it becomes horizontally scrollable.

See here:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS and to also hide the horizontal scrollbar, if not how is it done with Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't control input (such mouse wheel) with CSS, so you can't do an horizontal scroll only with CSS. You have to use JS at some point.

Comment: And how can I do this?

Comment: Here you have a [hint](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/) ;)

Comment: I think you can find the solution here here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660370/how-to-make-jquery-ui-tabs-scroll-horizontally-if-there-are-too-many-tabs?rq=1 Jquery UI can handle it.