# Unable to apply horizontal scroll for the Tabs in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am unable to apply the horizontal `scroll` to the Tabs using material UI.

below link is the material ui version i am using
https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs

The number of Tabs increasing its taking more width.

I trid to apply width, but its taking entire Tabs tab.

I need to apply only Tabs width and horizontal scroll.

```js
<Tabs
inkBarStyle={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} 
value={this.state.tableNameTab}
onChange={this.handleChangeTab}
key = "tabsData"
style={{ maxWidth: "500px", overflow: "auto" }}
>
{this.state.TableDetails.map( (data,index) =>
<Tab 
label={data.tableName} value={data.tableName}
key={'key'+index}
>
<h6>{data.tableName}</h6>
</Tab>
)
}
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

> Using `scrollable-force-tab` you can achieve inside `scoll` of `tabs`
>   header

Its mention in their [Official Doc](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#forced-scroll-buttons) please have a look

Comment: i am using https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs (Version V0.20.1), could you please assist me to solve this one

Comment: Why not using latest version?

Comment: We have used old version in number of pages

Comment: @ramumothukuri then may be this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660370/how-to-make-jquery-ui-tabs-scroll-horizontally-if-there-are-too-many-tabs